# Oracle: Faster writing while keeping the reading time low

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle Table containing 50 Mio. rows and a software that computes sets of data. Each set has 10,000 rows of the same category, so that they can be indexed. Each row of a single set has the same index value (e.g. let’s call it “AAA”, “AAB” , “AAC”, …). I have a maximum of 5000 categories. After the set is computed, the Software checks, whether the set (“AAB”) is already in the database (reading) and then updates or writes the data set to the database. I’m not interested in single rows, I just need to filter for a certain set of data (index = “AAB”), that is later downloaded.
Now with every set written to the database, the process takes more and more time. If I run tests – I get the following results:

- Test 1: Drop primary key: writing is 10 times faster, reading is 1000 times slower
- Test 2: Index, but no primary key: reading is very fast, but writing is 5 times slower than Test 1

The writing time of Test 1 is perfect, but reading is not acceptable. How can I optimize the process?
I was thinking, is it possible to use an index or something similar to find groups/set of data fast, but not sort them, only append the set at the end of the table? Because each set that I load into the database has already all associated rows bundled. Then even if I search by O(n) I only have 5000 different categories, that should not take so much time to find/delete a category, right? But just appending the set would be very fast. Now I don’t know how to do it, is it even possible? Does it make sense? Are there better options to optimize the process? How to do it (Oracle syntax would be helpful)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you considered partitioning on index value (or category - I'm not sure if they're the same thing)?

Comment: It's rare to remove a primary key to improve the write performance of inserting only 10,000 rows. Maybe you're experiencing an extreme hardware or design issue; is the I/O ridiculously slow, is the "set" processing inserting and committing one row at a time, are there expensive triggers, is the application inserting 10,000 rows concurrently all day long, etc. For extreme I/O issues with primary keys, it may help to use [scalable sequences](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/scalable-sequences-18c) that prepend different values to the primary key to reduce hot blocks and increase concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two configurations:

- configuration1: Read is slow, write is fast
- configuration2: Read is fast, write is slow

A handy solution is to have your table stored twice. You would do the frequent writing into the copy where the write is fast and do the reading from where the read is fast. This would mean that you would have to periodically purge the table where read is fast and copy the actual data into it.

Now, one may have two objections:

- the first objection is that data will no longer be fully live. That's true, but performance comes at a price
- the second objection is that doing the synchronization is slow, it could take many minutes. This is also true, but nothing is stopping you from creating a new cache table and use the old cache table for reading while the synchronization is in process and then remove the old cache table once the sync is complete

Comment: That solution feels needlessly cumbersome, especially for Oracle. The preferred method would be to partition the table and indexes so that both read and write operations are dealing with *much* smaller chunks of data. Don't forget that duplicating the data also means a +100% storage increase (double data, increased archive logs, backup size, cpu usage, etc.), which could directly affect operating cost and not just user experience. Partitioning as suggested by @AlexPoole is the only option that is scalable in terms of performance with minimal affect on system requirements and cost.